# How to factorize the above expression?

Tags: factoring

How to factorize $x^4+x+7$? I am trying this question by adding and subtracting $x^2$. So, the expression is becoming $(x^4+x^2+x+7)-x^2$. Now I am trying to factorize $x^2+x+7$ first. So, therefore $x^2+x+7=x^2+2\times x \times (1/2)+(1/2)^2+7-(1/2)^2$. So, finally I am getting $x^2+x+7=(x+1/2)^2+27/4$. So, the actual expression is becoming $x^4+(x+1/2)^2+(27/4)-x^2$. But I can't approach further. Please help me out with this factorization.

Comment: In general, factoring one polynomial doesn't help us factor the sum of that polynomial with another one (the same as for factoring integers, actually).

Comment: You should state where you are trying to factor this polynomial (over what field, e.g. rational or real or even complex numbers).  Assuming real/complex, graphing it quickly shows there are no real roots, so there must be 4 complex roots, which means it does factor over the complex numbers, but that gives no information on actually finding the roots which leads to the factorization.

Comment: How will it factor over the complex numbers?

Comment: That polynomial does not have nice factors and roots. (That is true of most random polynomials - why do you think this one should factor?)

Comment: Since [WolframAlpha's *Exact forms* solutions to $x^4 + x + 7 = 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%5E4+%2B+x+%2B+7+%3D+0) involves cube roots of non-real numbers, which cannot always be expressed in real radical form (see [this 1985 paper by Issacs](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323164); also some MSE posts, but I'd rather not cite them to avoid linking them to this question). Assuming that WolframAlpha would use real radical form if possible, then a factorization of your polynomial into quadratic factors must make use of numbers that cannot be expressed in real radical form.

Comment: @EthanBolker, are you trying to say that $x$⁴$+$$x$$+$7 can't be factorized?

Comment: For those interested, regarding the end of my last comment (I ran out of characters for a single comment), if a quadratic has real radical number coefficients, then its roots will have real radical number coefficients. This follows easily from the fact that the square root of a complex number involves only rational and square root expressions of the real and imaginary parts of the complex number. Thus, if the roots of a quadratic are not real radical numbers, then at least one of the quadratic's coefficients is not a real radical number.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(x^4+x+\frac{a^4}{4}-\frac{1}{4a^2}\right)=\left(x^2+a x +\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2a}\right)\left(x^2-a x +\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2a}\right)$$

Now find a real number $a$ such that
$$7=\frac{a^4}{4}-\frac{1}{4a^2}$$

This is a cubic in $a^2$

**EDIT**: going further, based on two comments by @Will Jagy

Let $t=a^2$ and note that the resulting cubic  $t^3-28t-1=0$ has a real root $t>0$

Also, the factorization can be written in the form of a difference of two squares as follows

$$\left(x^4+x+\frac{a^4}{4}-\frac{1}{4a^2}\right)=\left(x^2+\frac{a^2}{2}\right)^2-\left(a x -\frac{1}{2a}\right)^2$$

Comment: very nice, $t = a^2,$   $ t^3 - 28 t - 1 =0$

Comment: meanwhile, $  (x^2 + \frac{a^2}{2})^2 - (ax - \frac{1}{2a})^2  $ Assuming I have it correct, recommend you add that to your answer; I think the contests like working on a quartic as a difference of squares.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me out with this question